# How to create and open a docx in client side's Word from asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create and open a docx in client side's Word from asp.net application?
and if i want the user to customize the document at their localend, then
how can i do this?

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to accomplish and how, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use word automation(COM) model at client end to create word document in ASP.NET applications - but you can always use that on server end to create word document on server and send (allow to download) them to client. Trick (while using on server side) is to target the lowest possible word version - for example, if you use word interop assemblies for word 2003 then created documents could be open on clients having word 2003 and higher.